# Erro:java.lang.NullPointerException at user.Mein.main(Mein.java:15)

Tags: java

Alguém pode me esclarecer um pouco, está dando erro na linha em que começo a preencher o array do usuário.

```
public Usuario(String nome, String sobrenome, String cargo,int idade,double salario) {
    this.nome = nome;
    this.sobrenome = sobrenome;
    this.cargo = cargo;
    this.idade = idade;
    this.salario = salario;
}

public void promover(double porcentagem) {
    this.salario += salario*porcentagem/100;
}


public double getSalario() {
    return salario;
}

public void setSalario(double salario) {
    this.salario = salario;
}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

public String getSobrenome() {
    return sobrenome;
}

public void setSobrenome(String sobrenome) {
    this.sobrenome = sobrenome;
}

public String getCargo() {
    return cargo;
}

public void setCargo(String cargo) {
    this.cargo = cargo;
}

public int getIdade() {
    return idade;
}

public void setIdade(int idade) {
    this.idade = idade;
}

public String paraString() {
    return "Nome: " + nome + "\n" +
            "Sobrenome: " + sobrenome + "\n" +
            "Idade : " +idade + "\n" +
            "Cargo: " + cargo + "\n" +
            "Id: " + ID + "\n" +
            "Salario: " + salario;
}
public String toString() {
    return "Usuario [salario=" + salario + ", nome=" + nome + ", sobrenome=" + sobrenome + ", cargo=" + cargo
            + ", id=" + ID + ", idade=" + idade + "]";
}
```

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) {  
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);  
    Usuario[] user = new Usuario[5];  
    int i;  
    int porcentagem,id_cont=1;

     for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        System.out.println("Usuario " +i+ ", preencha seus dados, por favor!\n");
        System.out.println("Seu id será gerado automaticamente\n");
        System.out.println("Nome");
        user[i].ID = id_cont++;
        user[i].setNome(s.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Sobrenome");
        user[i].setSobrenome(s.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Cargo");
        user[i].setCargo(s.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Idade");
        user[i].setIdade(s.nextInt());
        s.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Salario");
        user[i].setSalario(s.nextDouble());
        s.nextLine();

        i++;
     }



    System.out.println("Digite a porcentagem de aumento dos usuarios");
    while(i<5) {
        porcentagem = s.nextInt();
        user[i].promover(porcentagem);
        porcentagem = 0;
        i++;
    }



    while(i<5) {
        System.out.println(user[i].paraString());
        System.out.println(user[i].toString());
        i++;
    }


    s.close();


}
```

Comment: Olá, insira o código na pergunta e não o print da sua tela. Existe a opção para inserir código.

Comment: pronto, valeu por avisar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu código tem alguns problemas, o primeiro problema e que foi descrito na sua pergunta está no método `main` nas seguintes linhas:

```
System.out.println("Nome");
user[i].ID = id_cont++;
user[i].setNome(s.nextLine());
```

O que acontece é que ao instanciar um array como você faz em `Usuario[] user = new Usuario[5];` apenas é instanciado o espaço em memória e não os objetos em si logo você precisa instanciar um objeto Usuario, preencher-lo com os dados e só então inserir o objeto no array.

Outro problema é que você colocou `i++` na última linha do seu `for` porém a diretiva `for` já faz o incremento da variavel a cada interação como você pode ver na linha `for(i=0;i<5;i++)`. No seu código por ter um `i++` ao final do `for` a cada interação ele incrementará 2 na variavel `i` o que causará uma `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

O último problema se enconta nas suas instruções `while(i < 5)`, o problema aqui é que você usa a mesma variavel de controle que usou no `for` porém neste ponto o valor de `i` deverá ser 6 pois ele foi incrementado durante a execução do `for` logo os `while(i < 5)` sempre serão falsos e nunca serão executados, para corrigir basta reinicializar o valor da variavel com 0.

Seu código com as devidas correções ficaria assim:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    Usuario[] user = new Usuario[5];
    int i;
    int porcentagem, id_cont = 1;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println("Usuario " + i + ", preencha seus dados, por favor!\n");
        System.out.println("Seu id será gerado automaticamente\n");

        // Instancia o objeto usuario
        Usuario usuario = new Usuario();

        // Define os valores para o objeto usuario
        System.out.println("Nome");
        usuario.ID = id_cont++;
        usuario.setNome(s.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Sobrenome");
        usuario.setSobrenome(s.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Cargo");
        usuario.setCargo(s.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Idade");
        usuario.setIdade(s.nextInt());
        s.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Salario");
        usuario.setSalario(s.nextDouble());
        s.nextLine();

        // Define esta instancia do objeto Usuario para o indice i do array
        user[i] = usuario;
    }

    // Reinicializa a variavel de controle i
    i = 0;
    System.out.println("Digite a porcentagem de aumento dos usuarios");
    while (i < 5) {
        porcentagem = s.nextInt();
        user[i].promover(porcentagem);
        porcentagem = 0;
        i++;
    }


    // Reinicializa a variavel de controle i
    i = 0;
    while (i < 5) {
        System.out.println(user[i].paraString());
        System.out.println(user[i].toString());
        i++;
    }

    s.close();

}
```

Para que o código acima funcione implemente o construtor padrão sem argumentos na sua classe Usuario:

```
// Construtor padrao sem argumentos
public Usuario() {

}
```

Por fim uma sugestão, utilize a instrução `for` quando souber a quantidade máxima de repetições e utilize a instrução `while` quando não soube a quantidade máxima de interações. No seu código, por exemplo, as instruções de repetição sempre executam 5 vezes logo um `for` seria mais adequado.

Comment: Muito obrigado, me ajudou bastante!